# Testing Chrome using Selenium-WebDriver while offline in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I am using Chrome, and I would like to be able to run automation tests in C# that tests while the application is offline (I am testing a mobile app with `PhoneGap`), and later on get online to complete the tests. Is it possible using `WebDriver` in `Selenium 2` ?

In Google Chrome you can set on developers tool like shown bellow:
[image]

But I don't know how to set it automatically on Selenium.

I know there is a way to check if application is online/offline by checking the 
`navigator.onLine` property, but I would like to "fake" it's values for testing purposes;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium is only for web based applications, which means **that you cannot run your automation tests when application is offline.**

It just replicates the user actions / behavior. If your user can access your site being in offline mode, then selenium also can do & vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Vikram, but where did you see this information ? Just because is web based doesn't mean it can't run offline. On the picture above I am a user able to access the website in offline mode using the developer's tools.

Comment: @Tito,  As I mentioned, If the user can access the website offline, then selenium also can do. As per my understanding, using "offline" mode in developer tools will retrieve pages from cache. But in Selenium webdriver, it creates a new fresh profile for each execution and will not use existing cache. That is my point. To access existing local cache and profile, there are some workaround (Need to check my old codes).  But I do not think that will open the pages through cache.

Answer (score 0):

@Tito @Vikram piece of code that works perfect for me:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.NetworkConditions = new ChromeNetworkConditions()
        { IsOffline = true, DownloadThroughput = 5000, UploadThroughput = 5000, Latency = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5) };
```

now you are in offline mode.
to switch it back you need to set IsOffline = false.

In Selenium4 for C# the property NetworkConditions they promised will be in IWebDriver interface